# PySpark read.csv - interaction between inferSchema and mode options

Tags: python, pyspark

I'm trying to read a csv while inferring the schema:

```
df = spark.read.csv('path/to/csv',
inferSchema=True,
header=True)
```

However, my data has some malformed rows, which causes the values from some columns to spill into their neighbouring columns.

So I set the mode to DROPMALFORMED:

```
df = spark.read.csv('path/to/csv',
inferSchema=True,
header=True,
mode='DROPMALFORMED')
```

This gets rid of the malformed rows, but the data types I get from inferSchema are the same as before.

For example, one column was all floats, except for a malformed row which inserted a string. So in the first version of the code, a string type column was inferred.
I was expecting that after adding the DROPMALFORMED option, it would then correctly infer a float type column, but instead I still got a string type.

Is there any way to get it to infer the schema after dropping malformed rows? Or do I have to resave without malformed rows and then re-read the data?

Comment: What version of spark are you using?

Comment: Spark version is 2.2